# How do I create and pay a Stripe order in a single API call?

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe.js

Stripe `order`s have a [`create` method](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_order) and a separate [`pay` method](https://stripe.com/docs/api#pay_order).

If I use these two different endpoints I need to make two HTTP calls to (1) create an order and then (2) pay it.

However, I would like to create and pay an order in a single HTTP call because that will be faster and is also consistent with the user experience I want to provide.

Is it possible to do this? If not is there a good workaround? I suppose I could create a `charge` immediately and then an `order` in the background and associate the `charge` with the `order` after the fact?

BONUS POINTS if there's a way to create a `customer` in the same API call in which I create and pay the `order`.

Comment: Have you tried checkout API?

Answer (score 2):

The create and pay process is two separate cURL call. So the minimum call is two.

Comment: I've been thinking about this, you can actually create a proxy to handle these two transaction if you insist on doing one http request.